# Dynamic form names and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-validation

I need to create several forms on a page based on a dynamic list I get from server. In order to do that I'm trying to use angular `ng-repeat` like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data.rows" ng-show="row.edit" class="edit_row" style="border: 0;">
    <td>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="{{ row.row_id }}">
                ...
                <input ng-disabled="{{ row.row_id }}.$invalid" value="Save" name="submit" type="submit" ng-click="collection.save_edit(row.row_id);">
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This doesn't work as expected - form has its `name` attribute generated properly, but angular is not picking this up. Is there a way to create a form with dynamic name? Or is there a workaround for this issue?

Only idea that comes to my mind is to somehow create `FormControllers` along with data.rows and use them in `ng-repeat` but I couldn't find a way to do it either.

Comment: what do you mean by "angular is not picking this up"?

Comment: I mean I can't find a way to pass `FormController` to `save_edit` method called on submit click (if I use hardcoded name for a form it works). Also I can't find a way to bind to this form's `.$invalid` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access form object from the `this` context of the $scope method, which would represent the child scope anyways. Since it is dynamic form name you pass in the form name and form control will always be attached to the scope with the same name as that of the form. So you could do wither by accessing it on the method or using `$scope[row.row_id].$invalid` explicitly on the view. Just to be safe i have use `ng-attr-name` to expand interpolation and set the form name dynamically.

```
  /*Get form object on save*/
  $scope.save_edit = function(form){
    console.log(this[form]);
  }

  /*Returns whether the form is valid or not*/
  $scope.isInvalid = function(form){
    return this[form].$invalid; 
  }
```

and your form would just be:

```
<form novalidate method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      ng-attr-name="{{ row.row_id }}">
    <input type="text" name="test" ng-required="true" ng-model="row.test"/>
    <input ng-disabled="isInvalid(row.row_id)" value="Save" name="submit" 
           type="submit" ng-click="save_edit(row.row_id);">
 </form>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fm1W4G528xP4SKgvAnPR?p=preview)**

Side note: In order to be more specific and separate out the form specific functionality you could move these to another controller and set `ng-controller` at the `ng-repeat` level, with that you could just use `$scope` instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to angular and for some reason I didn't realize I can can bind to a result of a function:-). You have also mentioned that I can do _this using `$scope[row.row_id].$invalid` explicitly on the view_ but when I try to do this: `ng-disabled="$scope[row.row_id].$invalid"` it doesn't work. Am I missing something?